# How to swap global variables with a function

Tags: python, variables, swap

I want to make a function where if I give 2 variables, it will swap the values of them GLOBALLY. e.g. a = 1, b = 2. I want to make it go like a = 2, b = 1.
Here is the code

```
    def swap(n,n2):
        n,n2 = n2,n
        print(n,n2)
```

I also tried this code:

```
    def swap(n,n2):
     temp = n
     n = n2
     n2 = temp
     global x
     global x2
     x = n
     x2 = n2
     print(x,x2)
```

I tried it, but it didn't swap the variables globally. Help pls.

Comment: Nope. Not how Python variables work.

Comment: The advice you dont want to hear is dont use global variables, and moreover changing global variables inside a random function does not look like a good practice, which can bite you later. What's your use-case?

Comment: Isn't `a, b = b, a` enough for your?

Comment: ```global``` access global scope

Answer (score 0):

Swapping variables inside a function effect only the scope of the function.

Use [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) to access global scope dictionary:

```
global sabich1
global sabich2

sabich1, sabich2 = 1, 2

def swap(n,n2):
    globals()[n], globals()[n2] = globals()[n2], globals()[n]

swap('sabich1', 'sabich2')

# 2 1
print(sabich1, sabich2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to refer global variables inside the function.
Refer below code.

```py
n=1
n2=2

def swap():
    global n,n2
    n,n2 = n2,n
    
print(n,n2)
swap()
print(n,n2)
```

**Output**

```
1 2
2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe you can do something like this:

```
a = 1
b = 2

def swap(var1, var2):
    var1, var2 = var2, var1
    return var1, var2

a, b = swap(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Python is passed by value not pass by reference.  So there is a new copy of the parameters that will be formed and they are been swapped not the original ones.